# Android: Query model before adding to RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-query

I have Tab/ViewPager Layout all consists of RecyclerView with datas depending on 'ID', What I tried so far is to get all the data in my model and add to adapter, then set the visibility to hide others data but it just leaves a blank space without the layout in my recyclerview. So i would like to query it first and just pick all the ID's with 245 before adding the result to my adapter.

Guys I'm trying to remove some items in recycler view by

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final int i = holder.getAdapterPosition();

        int id = mDataset.getCargoItem().get(i).getCargoStatusId();
        if (id != 245){
            holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Please comment if you need more of my codes

Answer (score 0):

change this ..

```
    int id = mDataset.getCargoItem().get(position).getCargoStatusId();
```